# how we can use refering url to navigate a website in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

If i want to navigate a website like http://example.com/
i want that when website navigated then it show that example has a page reference like https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=need+help
so what will be the code? for this in visual basic

here is my code

```
Public Class Form1

Dim pageReverence As String = "google.com.pk/search?q=need+help"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim website As String = txtWebsite.Text
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(website, pageReverence.ToString)

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it be

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(pageReverence)
```

Im not sure what `Dim website As String = txtWebsite.Text` is for

Comment: Dim website As String = txtWebsite.Text is website to be navigated
like http://example.com
so now i want that example.com is navigated with page reference of google search

Comment: WebBrowser1.Navigate(pageReverence)
this will navigate this url "google.com.pk/search?q=need+help"
butt i want to navigate example.com and with reverence of pageReverence

Comment: do you mean to search for "google.com.ph/search?q=example.com"?

Comment: no,
now read carefully,
let suppose example.com is facebook.com
when we open google.com and search facebook.com on google
then the page will be https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook.com
and the first link will be https://www.facebook.com/‎ of google search
here is my point
when we open first link on google search https://www.facebook.com/‎
then facebook will show that facebook has source of google search
and i want that this hole step by my vb app
i want that navigation of facebook.com by the page source of google search....
please help me for this

Comment: I have heard that it is possible with headers...?